# Regular expression to differentiate function call and variable declaration in custom language

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build regex to differentiate variable declaration and function calls in custom language.

Variable declaration looks like this:

```
let var1(string)
let var2 (string)
let var3,var4,var5(string)
```

Function call looks like this:

```
func1(1,2..)
func2()
->func3()
```

Regex I used for the function call is

```
(?i:(?![let])\s*(\b[a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*?\b)(?=\(\)?))
```

This regex matches variable declaration as well. If there is **let** keyword in front of the variable I want to exclude it in this regex.

Regex for the variable match is here:

```
(?i:((?<=(\\+|=|-|\\&|\\\\|/|<|>|\\(|,))\\s*\\b([a-zA-Z_xf-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_xf-xff]*?)\\b(?!(\\(|\\.))|\\b([a-zA-Z_xf-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_xf-xff]*?)\\b(?=\\s*(\\.|\\+|=|-|\\&|\\\\|/|<|>|\\(|\\)))))
```

This regex matches ***let var1 (String)*** but not ***let var1(String)***

I already spent enough time trying to figure out this :( . Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below regex for the function call solved the issue. It's able to differentiate variable vs function call.

```
(?i:(?<=(\.|\>|=))\s*(\b[a-zA-Z_x7f-xff][a-zA-Z0-9_x7f-xff]*?\b)(?=\(\)?))
```

Thanks to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)